# big(in size) PNG performance problems in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, png, sprite

I have a huge performance problems displaying (that's it, just loading the page is enough for my cpu to go apeshit) [this website](http://zumba2.f13.cz/) in Google Chrome: CPU usage goes as high as 90%.

Figured it's the huge PNG sprite causing it, it's 700x24600 and 5190kb, is there anything I could do apart from waiting for Chrome team to fix their code? And other than doing something like storing each "frame" in a different file?

Note that there are no problems with FireFox, MS Internet Explorer, Opera and even Safari.

Comment: I have no problem on this site with crome, works fine for me.

Comment: try clicking on "co je to zumba" or using some less powerfull rig, like a notebook.

Also it's Chrome 16.0.912.77 I have the problems in.

Comment: It hangs my Chrome too, and I have Chrome 16, plenty of RAM free and an i5 2.5 GHz...

Comment: Chrome 17; it does not peg out my CPU/memory but the page is unusably laggy. FWIW I note that if in the console I $("#image").hide(); wait for it to return then $("#image").show(); it becomes as responsive as any other browser, no idea why (.hide().show() does not do this). IMHO a 5mb+ sprite is really too large anyway.

Comment: So I just tried to switch to PNG8 with 256 colors, making the png only 1.2mb, but it hangs totally the way as when it was 5mb, so the problem is rather with its dimensions than filesize. Thus making me even more convince that there is something wrong with Chrome and that I can't do much about it. 
I was thinking about making the sprite horizontal, if that would change anything..

Answer (score 0):

That is a really large image. It hangs for me in both Chrome and Firefox. Regardless of hanging issues, even if it loaded successfully, the load time of your page is going to be seriously impaired by such a large image. Unless you really think that the value of the image as it stands outweighs the time it takes to load, I would consider replacing it with something much smaller.

However you might try optimizing it first. Have you used any lossless compression tools such as optipng to see if that has much of an impact reducing the size?

Comment: Well there's gonna be a preloader, so much for the loading time, as for the optipng, I'm on it now..

Comment: As I said in the comment above, the filesize is probably not a problem here, after making the picture _just_ 1.2mb, it was just as laggy. Must be the dimensions and Chrome code..

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, when I made that sprite horizontal, it stopped lagging.

// edit
ok, not really, after refreshing the page it started lagging again..